# CMake error "Can not find target to add properties to"

Tags: cmake

In my CMakeLIsts.txt file I write this:

```
set(LIBHELLO_SRC hello.c)
set_target_properties(hello_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "hello")
get_target_property(OUTPUT_VALUE hello_static OUTPUT_NAME)
message(STATUS "This is the hello_static OUTPUT_NAME:"${OUTPUT_VALUE})
```

When I run `cmake`, it shows the error message:

```
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: hello_static
```

Comment: Maybe your target name or path is wrong or have not been created yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For your code to work, `hello_static` *must* be the name of a CMake target; something which is added via the [`add_executable`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_executable) or [`add_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_library) commands for example.

This is unrelated to the name of your project.

It looks like you're missing something like:

```
add_library(hello_static ${LIBHELLO_SRC})
```

which would be placed immediately after

```
set(LIBHELLO_SRC hello.c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
project(hello_static)
set(LIBHELLO_SRC hello.c)
add_executable(hello_static ${LIBHELLO_SRC})
set_target_properties(hello_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "hello")
get_target_property(OUTPUT_VALUE hello_static OUTPUT_NAME)
message(STATUS "This is the hello_static OUTPUT_NAME:"${OUTPUT_VALUE})
```

This works for me.

But if you just want a "hello" executable. you can  reduced this to:

```
project(hello_static)
set(LIBHELLO_SRC hello.c)
add_executable(hello ${LIBHELLO_SRC})
```

Comment: Do you mean I should ensure my project name is hello_static?

Comment: Yes. That the easiest, if this is what you want to do.

Comment: I have change my project name to hello_static,but it does not work

Comment: > set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: hello_static

Comment: This was my issue (the misleading error message), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

remove the generated c files in created lib (might be showing in build failed)

then run `git submodule update --init --recursive`

in the same module.