# WIth what to replace set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: myTarget?

Tags: cmake

So the question is very straightforward.
I have the following CMakeList.txt (I copy only the first lines because I believe the rest is not important):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

###############              Project name          #####################
project(myProject)

###############            Minimal flags           #####################   
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH)
  set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
endif()

#######   Check the compiler and set the compile and link flags  #######
set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../config/cmake")
```

but I get the following error:

```
Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: myTarget
```

I found this: [CMake error "Can not find target to add properties to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110336/cmake-compile-error)
But I think this is not the case. Because of this: https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/features/small.html

All the examples I've seen are similar to that code says I have to do add a library as target but  don't know which library should I use.

Do you know what's wrong or with what to replace myTarget?

Comment: You can only set target properties on already existing targets. So you need to add the target first by adding a `add_library` / `add_executable` / `add_custom_command` call to your CMakeLists.txt. After that you can set properties on it.

Comment: Actually, the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110336/cmake-error-can-not-find-target-to-add-properties-to describes **exactly your problem**. And an assumtion "I believe the compiler should already know what myTarget is." is simply wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake error "Can not find target to add properties to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110336/cmake-error-can-not-find-target-to-add-properties-to)

Comment: The main problem is that the code is not mine. Maybe they uploaded a broken version to git. Do I have a way to know what lib to set with `add_library(myTarget ${WHAT_LIB})`?
myTarget is not used on the rest of the CMakeList.txt... Is it safe then just to delete that part?

Comment: What git project are we talking about? It is often easier for us to give sound advise if all information is known.

Comment: It's a private repo of my company. That's why I didn't gave the git. But the guy who did the code is no longer with us.

Comment: I understand. If the target in question is not used throughout the entire CMakeLists.txt, I think it's safe to delete it. If you need the settings for all other C++ targets too, replace the call to `set_target_properties` with the following commands in your CMakeLists.txt `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`. That should work.

Comment: This solved my life! It compiled and so far it seams to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @vre said. Just changing `set_target_properties` to:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Was good enough and it compiled correctly.